# Why does JSFiddle show scrollbars when setting <html> and <body> to 100%

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

Why does JSFiddle (and also the other JS playgrounds I tried) do present Scrollbars when setting the `width` and `height` style of `body` and `html` element to 100%? [A simple example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wodpy8dx/). This wouldn't happen on a "pure" site.

Is there a way to solve this without overflow hidden? I need this to present a specific problem where that matters. Do you know of any alternatives where this works correctly?

Comment: Try inspecting the document next time

Comment: "This wouldn't happen on a "pure" site." - It most definitely does, default margins/padding are the main motivation for CSS "reset" files like this one: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ or those included in most frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most browsers add a margin to the document by default, which causes the overflow at 100%;

Add this style:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
```